# What does each color mean in Chrome devtools profile flame chart

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, profiler

When I use Chrome devtools's profile tool to record javascript CPU run time, and switch to flame chart, I see lots color blocks, some block's color look similar, some are different.

What does each kind of color represent? What are the differences?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Colors are only there to make chart readable (and pretty!), there is no special meaning associated with them. Each function gets a random color that allows you to easily spot calls to the same function.

I've made two snapshots of exactly the same [code](http://jsbin.com/AYAyewa/1/edit) below (restarting DevTools in between):
[image: flame chart #1]
[image: flame chart #2]

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned on the [Chrome Dev Site](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling)

> "The colors in the Flame Chart fairly random, however functions will always be colored the same across invocations. This allows you to see a pattern of execution and then spot outliers easier. There is no correlation to the colors used in the Timeline."